# How to delete what is inside a path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am new to Photoshop, and I can't find the answer of this anywhere, everyone is talking about how to add or remove anchor point from a path, but when I create a path over a shape or other part of my project, and make a selection, and then click delete or backspace, nothing changes.

I just want to delete what inside that path, not using any Stamp Clone or any other utility, I have spent hours actually on this, without any progress, so I need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you close the path?

Comment: Yes I did in fact, The error message is that I didn't select any layer, but finally I solved this by simply selecting the layer and using the eraser, apparently the path is for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a path into a selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the contents of the selection.

Comment: I did this in the first place, but no thing was deleted.

Comment: Are you on the correct layer?